# Problem related to reading input from file

Tags: c, function, file, project

So we are trying to make a simple banking program in C language. There is a text file called AccountInfo.txt that contains information like account holders name, account number, account type, nid, phone number etc. One of the features of the program is a single user can have multiple bank accounts. So I was trying to implement that feature via an user defined function called SearchAndFind that will search the text files and print all the account numbers that matches with the user provided username. Here's the code:
(Please note that the code is still incomplete and inefficient as well. Kindly ignore that)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define USER_PASS "./username.txt"
#define ACCOUNT_DATA "./AccountInfo.txt"

typedef struct
{
    char Name[30];
    char AccountType[20];
    long long AccountNo;
    long long Balance;
    long long Phone;
    long long NID;
    char Username[30];
} AccountInfo;

int loginverify(char *userid, char *pass);
void createaccount();
void mainmenu(char *usernm);
int ReadAccountInfo();
void ViewAccounts(char *usrnm, int sumaccounts);
void SearchAndPrint(char *username);

int main()
{
    int flag, signinoption;
    char user_name[20], password[30];
    printf("Welcome to My Bank\n");
    while (1)
    {
        printf("1. Login\n");
        printf("2. Create a new account\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");
        printf("Choose your option: ");
        scanf("%d", &signinoption);
        printf("\n");
        switch (signinoption)
        {
        case 1:
            while (1)
            {
                printf("Enter Username: ");
                scanf("%19s", user_name);
                printf("Enter Password: ");
                scanf("%29s", password);
                flag = loginverify(user_name, password);

                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    printf("\nLogin successful. \n");
                    printf("\n");
                    mainmenu(user_name);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Login Failed. Try again. \n");
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            createaccount();
            break;
        case 3:
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        if (signinoption == 1)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void mainmenu(char *usernm)
{
    int menuchoice = 100;
    char usrnm[30];
    strcpy(usrnm, usernm);
    while (menuchoice != 12)
    {

        printf("1. View All Accounts\n");
        printf("2. Check Balance\n");
        printf("3. Cash Deposit\n");
        printf("4. Cash Withdraw\n");
        printf("5. Fund Transfer\n");
        printf("6. Benificiary Management\n");
        printf("7. Mini Statement\n");
        printf("8. Account Settings\n");
        printf("9. Close Account\n");
        printf("10. ATM/Branch Locations\n");
        printf("11. Customer Support\n");
        printf("12. Exit\n");

        printf("\n");
        printf("Choose your option: ");
        scanf("%d", &menuchoice);
        printf("\n");

        if (menuchoice == 1)
            SearchAndPrint(usrnm);
    }
}

int loginverify(char *userid, char *pass)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char user[20], password[30];
    int found = 0;

    fp = fopen(USER_PASS, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Could not open file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "Username: %s\nPassword: %s\n", user, password) == 2)
    {
        if (strcmp(userid, user) == 0 && strcmp(pass, password) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return found;
}

void createaccount()
{
    char username[20], password[20];
    printf("Enter your login credentials: \n");
    // a function can be added to check uniquenness
    printf("Enter Username: ");
    scanf("%s", username);
    printf("Enter Password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter your Account details: \n");
    printf("Enter your Name: ");
    printf("Enter your Account Type (Savings/Current/Fixed Deposit): ");
    // here unique account number is requires. or it can be generated automatically
    printf("Enter your Account No: ");
    printf("Enter your Balance: ");
    printf("Enter your Phone No: ");
    printf("Enter your NID No: ");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Account Created Successfully\n");
    printf("\n");
}

void SearchAndPrint(char *username)
{
    printf("\n%s\n", username);
    FILE *fp;
    AccountInfo acc;
    int found = 0;

    fp = fopen(ACCOUNT_DATA, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Could not open file\n");
        return;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "Name: %s\nAccount Type: %s\nAccount No: %lld\nBalance: %lld\nPhone: %lld\nNID No: %lld\nUsername: %s\n", acc.Name, acc.AccountType, &acc.AccountNo, &acc.Balance, &acc.Phone, &acc.NID, acc.Username) == 7)
    {
        printf("Name: %s\nAccount Type: %s\nAccount No: %lld\nBalance: %lld\nPhone: %lld\nNID No: %lld\nUsername: %s\n", acc.Name, acc.AccountType, acc.AccountNo, acc.Balance, acc.Phone, acc.NID, acc.Username);

        if (strcmp(username, acc.Username) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Account No: %lld\nAccount Type: %s\n", acc.AccountNo, acc.AccountType);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    if (!found)
    {
        printf("No matching accounts found\n");
    }
}
```

Now from main menu when I input 1, it goes to the SearchAndPrint function, then executes the line: printf("\n%s\n", username); but nothing afterwards. I have tried several methods but nothing works. My assumption there must be some problem reading the contents of file.

Here is what AccountInfo.txt file contains: https://pastebin.com/y2qypf3s

For login credentials, you can use any of the following: https://pastebin.com/iF1BTuZB

I tried different variants of while loop to take input from file. I was expecting to print out the Account Informations of all the entries that matches with the provided username.

Comment: The trailing newline in `while (fscanf(fp, "Username: %s\nPassword: %s\n", user, password) == 2)` might cause problems at the last line. I suggest `while (fscanf(fp, " Username: %s Password: %s", user, password) == 2)` with a space *before* any item where whitespace might be expected.

Comment: @WeatherVane tried but still getting the same problem. just in case i was facing issue in fscanf in the SearchAndFind function, not the one you mentioned

Comment: If you mean `SearchAndPrint` the same applies and I suggest changing `"Name: %s\nAccount Type: %s\nAccount No: %lld\nBalance: %lld\nPhone: %lld\nNID No: %lld\nUsername: %s\n"` to `" Name: %s Account Type: %s Account No: %lld Balance: %lld Phone: %lld NID No: %lld Username: %s"`. Added a leading space, changed every `\n` to a space, and removed the trailing `\n`.

Comment: Aside: don't store account and phone numbers as integer. These "numbers" are strings (you don't want to lose any leading zeros).

Comment: @WeatherVane tried that in SearchAndPrint function too. Still facing the same issue

Comment: The name is two words and you can't read that with `%s` because it stops at the first whitespace. Try `" Name: %[^\n] Account Type: %s Account No: %lld Balance: %lld Phone: %lld NID No: %lld Username: %s"`

Comment: Another aside: you must restrict the string length input, and you must check that `fscanf` scans the correct number of items.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks a lot. it resolved the issue. but facing another problem, the program is printing only the first matched account details. if the username repeats again later on in the text file with the same username, it won't print it. only the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In trying out your program, I also could not get any account information to list due to the fact of the account name actually being comprised of string with an embedded blank.  Having worked with the "scanf" function and strings with embedded blanks in previous code, I did try out some refactored code utilizing the formatting literal "%[^\n]" as noted in the good comments above.  However, in order to make that formatting literal work entailed a tweak to the account information file as well.

First off, following is a refactored version of your program with the refinement to the "fscanf" function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define USER_PASS "./username.txt"
#define ACCOUNT_DATA "./AccountInfo.txt"

typedef struct
{
    char Name[30];
    char AccountType[20];
    long long AccountNo;
    long long Balance;
    long long Phone;
    long long NID;
    char Username[30];
} AccountInfo;

int loginverify(char *userid, char *pass);
void createaccount();
void mainmenu(char *usernm);
int ReadAccountInfo();
void ViewAccounts(char *usrnm, int sumaccounts);
void SearchAndPrint(char *username);

int main()
{
    int flag, signinoption;
    char user_name[20], password[30];
    printf("Welcome to My Bank\n");
    while (1)
    {
        printf("1. Login\n");
        printf("2. Create a new account\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");
        printf("Choose your option: ");
        scanf("%d", &signinoption);
        printf("\n");
        switch (signinoption)
        {
        case 1:
            while (1)
            {
                printf("Enter Username: ");
                scanf("%19s", user_name);
                printf("Enter Password: ");
                scanf("%29s", password);
                flag = loginverify(user_name, password);

                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    printf("\nLogin successful. \n");
                    printf("\n");
                    mainmenu(user_name);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Login Failed. Try again. \n");
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            createaccount();
            break;
        case 3:
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        if (signinoption == 1)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void mainmenu(char *usernm)
{
    int menuchoice = 100;
    char usrnm[30];
    strcpy(usrnm, usernm);
    while (menuchoice != 12)
    {

        printf("1. View All Accounts\n");
        printf("2. Check Balance\n");
        printf("3. Cash Deposit\n");
        printf("4. Cash Withdraw\n");
        printf("5. Fund Transfer\n");
        printf("6. Benificiary Management\n");
        printf("7. Mini Statement\n");
        printf("8. Account Settings\n");
        printf("9. Close Account\n");
        printf("10. ATM/Branch Locations\n");
        printf("11. Customer Support\n");
        printf("12. Exit\n");

        printf("\n");
        printf("Choose your option: ");
        scanf("%d", &menuchoice);
        printf("\n");

        if (menuchoice == 1)
            SearchAndPrint(usrnm);
    }
}

int loginverify(char *userid, char *pass)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char user[20], password[30];
    int found = 0;

    fp = fopen(USER_PASS, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Could not open file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "Username: %s\nPassword: %s\n", user, password) == 2)
    {
        if (strcmp(userid, user) == 0 && strcmp(pass, password) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return found;
}

void createaccount()
{
    char username[20], password[20];
    printf("Enter your login credentials: \n");
    // a function can be added to check uniquenness
    printf("Enter Username: ");
    scanf("%s", username);
    printf("Enter Password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter your Account details: \n");
    printf("Enter your Name: ");
    printf("Enter your Account Type (Savings/Current/Fixed Deposit): ");
    // here unique account number is requires. or it can be generated automatically
    printf("Enter your Account No: ");
    printf("Enter your Balance: ");
    printf("Enter your Phone No: ");
    printf("Enter your NID No: ");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Account Created Successfully\n");
    printf("\n");
}

void SearchAndPrint(char *username)
{
    printf("User Name: %s\n", username);
    FILE *fp;
    AccountInfo acc;
    int found = 0;

    fp = fopen(ACCOUNT_DATA, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Could not open file\n");
        return;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "Name: %[^\n] \nAccount Type: %s\nAccount No: %lld\nBalance: %lld\nPhone: %lld\nNID No: %lld\nUsername: %s\n", acc.Name, acc.AccountType, &acc.AccountNo, &acc.Balance, &acc.Phone, &acc.NID, acc.Username) == 7)
    {
        if (strcmp(username, acc.Username) == 0)
        {
            printf("Name: %s\nAccount Type: %s\nAccount No: %lld\nBalance: %lld\nPhone: %lld\nNID No: %lld\n\n", acc.Name, acc.AccountType, acc.AccountNo, acc.Balance, acc.Phone, acc.NID);
            found = 1;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    if (!found)
    {
        printf("No matching accounts found\n");
    }
}
```

Some key bits to note.

- The input literal was changed to "%[^\n]" and a trailing space was added after that literal and the newline designation along with adding a space after the user's name in the account information file.
- Some small tweaks were made in the printing of the user name value in the "SearchAndPrint" function just for aesthetic purposes.

With those tweaks, following was the terminal output testing out the program for an account.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Banking/bin/Release$ ./Banking 
Welcome to My Bank
1. Login
2. Create a new account
3. Exit
Choose your option: 1

Enter Username: ElizabethSmith
Enter Password: G7FkPvHd3m

Login successful. 

1. View All Accounts
2. Check Balance
3. Cash Deposit
4. Cash Withdraw
5. Fund Transfer
6. Benificiary Management
7. Mini Statement
8. Account Settings
9. Close Account
10. ATM/Branch Locations
11. Customer Support
12. Exit

Choose your option: 1

User Name: ElizabethSmith
Name: Elizabeth Smith
Account Type: Savings
Account No: 6549873214
Balance: 93750
Phone: 8801912345678
NID No: 124356789

1. View All Accounts
2. Check Balance
3. Cash Deposit
4. Cash Withdraw
5. Fund Transfer
6. Benificiary Management
7. Mini Statement
8. Account Settings
9. Close Account
10. ATM/Branch Locations
11. Customer Support
12. Exit

Choose your option: 12
```

Give those tweaks a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: i followed your instruction. But it seems like the fscanf function works for only the first entry, which is Elizabeth Smith here. If I login with any other credentials, I get No matching accounts found as output

Comment: I just tried it out with Christopher Jones and Sarah Williams and got account information to display.  As I noted in the bullet points above, in order for the "fscanf" function to work, there needs to be a space after the person's last name prior to the newline character for each account set (e.g. "Christopher Jones ").  You might need to double check that bit.

Comment: After updating the text file it indeed seems to work with most of the accounts. But I still face the problem with few accounts like Megan Anderson and Ashley Moore. Also for Elizabeth Smith it prints only one account whereas there are two. 
Here's the updated text file: https://pastebin.com/pZxEXcCB
Can you please look into it?

Comment: Hi.  The issue again is where you have a string literal that contains an embedded blank - "Fixed Deposit".  That throws off any subsequent "fscanf" reading.  As a quick fix, I renamed all such accounts to "Fixed_Deposit" so that the literal string is contiguous, and that addressed finding other account data.  So, your possible solutions are to rename the "Fixed Deposit" literal, or revise the "fscanf" formatting code for that variable to utilize the "%[^\n]" formatting code along with adding a space after the account type literals (e.g. "Fixed Deposit ").  Give that a try.